# Can't enter password with xfce4

Tags: xfce

I have installed xfce on my Ubuntu 18.04 system as a more light-weight alternative to GNOME.
Today, my computer asked for the password but I was unable to enter text in the password text field. The keyboard works, seen by the fact that the password prompt detects caps lock and the keyboard could type the login in the virtual terminal. The problem reappears every 2 days.

Comment: It can be because of your default language. Which languages have you installed?

Comment: I have English international and Russian Phonetic QWERTY. It is set as "en".

Comment: Well I charged my laptop until it's off and turned it on with the "Novo" button. Fortunately, the password field worked, although I think it was in GNOME shell. I think one of the applications I had running may have caused such inconveniences.

Comment: I have experienced this issue the 3rd time today. It follows a pattern of repeating every 2 days, thus it's probably not a program causing this. It happened on the 12th,  14th and 16th.